# Not updating object variable with controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created table with employees and their tasks in Thymealeaf. Here I have fragment of code that is checking if employee is having task. If he dont have task, we can assign task for him. There problem begins.

```
<td>
    <span th:if="${employee.task==null}">No assigned task <a th:href="${'tasks/chooseTask/' + employee.id}">Assign task</a></span>
    <span th:if="${employee.task!=null}" th:text="${employee.task.description}"></span>
</td>
```

Here i have my method for choosing task for that employee in my TaskController.

```
@RequestMapping("tasks/chooseTask/{id}")
public String chooseTask(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model){
    List<Task> tasks =  tasksService.getAllTasks();
    model.addAttribute("tasks", tasks);
    Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
    model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
    return "chooseTask";
}
```

ChooseTask is table of tasks descriptions and buttons to choose. It looks like this:

```
<tbody th:each="task : ${tasks}">
    <tr>
         <td th:text="${task.description}"></td>
         <td><a th:href="${'/task/assign/'+task.id}">Choose</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And now I have method to assign task to that employee.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task/assign/{id}")
public String assignTask(@PathVariable("id")int id,  Employee employee){
    Task task = tasksService.getTaskById(id);
    employee.setTask(task);
    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```

It is not assinging tasks to employees, and dont update view of employees website.

Comment: Any Errors/exceptions you seeing in the application log output? And how do you pass `employee` model from view to Controller?

Comment: No there is no errors/exceptions, in arguments in method assignTask(?).

Answer (score 0):

Simply you are not saving the `employee` before redircting to `employees` view after setting the new task.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task/assign/{id}")
public String assignTask(@PathVariable("id")int id,  Employee employee){
    Task task = tasksService.getTaskById(id);
    employee.setTask(task);
    //you need to save employee here
    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```